# How to pass integer variable in sql query

Tags: sql, c#-4.0

```
int no = FormView1.PageIndex;
```

Query:-

```
  SqlCommand cmd =  new SqlCommand("select Answer from Questions where QuestionNo = @no", cn);
```

Comment: Use prepared statements.

Comment: So what is happening with your code. Is it failing, throwing an execption, unexpected results??

Answer (score 5):

You have to add a parameter:

```
int no = FormView1.PageIndex;
SqlCommand cmd = 
    new SqlCommand("select Answer from Questions where QuestionNo = @no", cn);

// Set the parameter up before executing the command
cmd.Parameters.Add("@no", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@no"].Value = no;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `SqlParameter` to the `SqlCommand`:

```
int no = FormView1.PageIndex;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Answer from Questions where QuestionNo = @no", cn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@no", no);
```

Answer (score 0):

use an array of System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter

```
SqlCommand cmd(...);
SqlParameter[] inQueryParameters = ...;
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(inQueryParameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SqlParameters. See the example below.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
SqlCommand ageCom = new SqlCommand("select age_phase from PatintInfo where patient_ID=@ptn_id", con);
ageCom.Parameters.Add("@ptn_id",SqlDbType.Int).Value=Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
```

It had worked in my program correctly.